# Which would be a complete list of "check Windows health" commands?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, bsod

I'm having problems with my PC and I need to run some diagnostics. I know there are a list of commands for `cmd` like `sfc /scannow`, but I don't know all of them by memory and different articles found on Google mention some of them some times, others other times.

So I would like to know the 'full list' of such commands for me to run every time my PC starts to have BSODs and the like and which work for W10.

Comment: Please describe the problems.  If you have already ran SFC, and no issues were found, then running the DISM command won’t solve your issue

Comment: I try (from an Admin Command Prompt) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and follow it with SFC /SCANNOW as you point out in your question. If that does not work and I think my Windows Profile is OK (does not cause BSOD), then I run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link

Comment: What error are you seeing from the BSOD detail?

Comment: If you (Author) perceive Driver errors, then (in addition to Windows fixes) update BIOS, Chipset, Video and all remaining drivers. I use the Manufacturer's update app to do this.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, but I'm focusing not on trying to solve a specific problem here (regarding BSOD, I kinda have all of them!), but actually learning the full list of 'check W10 health commands' pure and simple =)

Comment: If only fixing windows was as easy as typing a few commands.

Comment: I'd give [Windows Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) a try. Half is Windows' own checks & repairs, the other half is proprietary, by the app author. It will fix a whole lot of issues without needing to do anything except be patient & follow the instructions. Freeware version is sufficient for most people, but it's saved my skin often enough that I got the paid version just to reward the author [no affiliation, just a satisfied customer]

Comment: I would focus on learning the troubleshooting techniques and tools for different classes of problems. For each issue: There is collecting the right data and analyzing it. Example scenarios to consider: Process crash, bugcheck, system hang, high CPU, high paged/non-paged pool usage, etc.  Learning the following tools will cover 90% - Sysinternals Suite, WinDbg, Windows Performance Analyzer and Recorder, Wireshark.  Learning to program in a language, ideally, C++/C# will fast-track your troubleshooting skills. I would also recommend Windows Internals and anything created by Mark Russinovich.